# Rails 5 server side error handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say I have some code in my controller action and I am expecting params[:name] to be a string not empty. My user interface notifies the user that hea can't have empty string, but let's say someone uses an app like postman, can they cause the server to crash by sending an empty string that can cause errors because of methods being called on nil class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server would not "crash" in that scenario. In any case it will just raise an error and respond with a 500, but it will not "crash" as in making it unusable to process other requests